# Load a partitioned delta file in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

```
file = abfss://data@pragmaticworks.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/FG4P/
ref_Table = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_path)
```

> I have a folder with data partitioned by month in delta format. When i load the data, it loads on a particular month. How do i load the entire file.
> In the FG4P folder, we have partitioned data in folders
> month=01
> month=02
> month=03
> month=04
> month=05
>
> It loads only for a particular month but I want to load all the months in one data frame

Answer (score 1):

If you have data that is partitioned by month in different folders and you want to load all the data in one PySpark DataFrame, you can use the "option" method to specify the path to the parent directory of the partitions instead of the path to a specific partition. This will help you load all the partitions (i.e., all the months) in one data frame.

```
delta_path = "abfss://data@pragmaticworks.dfs.core.windows.net/delta/FG4P/" 
ref_Table = spark.read.format("delta").option("basePath", delta_path).load(delta_path)
```

In this example, you can set the base path to delta_path, which is the parent directory of the partitioned data by using the option("basePath", delta_path) method. This will help you load all the partitions in that directory into a single PySpark DataFrame using the load(delta_path) method.

Please note that the basePath option is only available in Delta Lake version 0.7.0 and later. In case you are using an earlier version, you can instead use the recursiveFileLookup option to include all the partitions in the directory. You can use the following code for that:

```
ref_Table = spark.read.format("delta").option("recursiveFileLookup", "true").load(delta_path)
```

The recursiveFileLookup option will tell Spark to recursively search for files in the specified path and load all the Delta tables it finds.

Comment: It still loads for just a single month with the base path option. There is a delta_log folder included in the base path along side the months folder

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do following to load all data:

```py
ref_Table = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_path)
```

then when you will need to have only specific month, you apply a filter operation on that dataframe, and Spark will optimize it to read only specific partition or partitions, depending on the filter condition.

```py
monthDF = ref_Table.filter("month = '01'")
```